# Compiling project that contains cpp and c files

Tags: visual-c++

I'm working on c++ project. One of my project files has extension `c`. Will compiler compile whole project using `c++` or it will compile `c++` files an c file separately and then link them somehow?

my c file contains code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

How compiler will deal with `c` file in case I set `Compile as C++ Code(/TP)` ?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx), looks like the 2nd option (.cpp as c++, .c as c). However, if you force with command line option, then it will follow the command line option. Note the case sensitivity of c and p after -T, it could mean ALL files or just the following file as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx).